# GlassFish deployment error: ComponentProvider is not found

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, glassfish, glassfish-4

This looks like a configuration problem in GlassFish which I cannot resolve. To make it worse, GlassFish deploys fine on one of my laptops, but not on the other.

Context: I am developing a RESTful service/API, building it with Maven, packaging it using war. My IDE is IntellijIDEA 14 with GlassFish 4.1.0 app server.

I am getting the following exception:

`RestAPI:war exploded: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.ServiceConfigurationError: org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.ComponentProvider: The class org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.CdiComponentProvider implementing the provider interface org.glassfish.jersey.server.spi.ComponentProvider is not found. The provider implementation is ignored.`

Both my machines have everything installed, Java, Java SDK, both run on Windows 8.1, etc.

I've spent the past two days googling for a solution but no luck. Has anyone encountered this problem?

P.S. I am fairly new to Java development, especially tools and frameworks, so I apologize if I've expressed myself in a incorrect way.